# Liferay: create user through SOAP webservices

Tags: soap, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to create a new user in Liferay using remote SOAP calls.
That's what I got so far (groovy):

```
public UserSoap addUser(UserInfo ui, String password) {
    def companyPort = companyServiceLocator.getPortal_CompanyService(new URL(companyBaseUrl))
    def userPort = serviceLocator.getPortal_UserService(new URL(userBaseUrl))
    // FIXME: this should come from configuration as well
    def company = companyPort.getCompanyByVirtualHost('localhost')
    def sites = new WebsiteSoap[0]
    def sc = new ServiceContext()
    sc.indexingEnabled = true
    sc.assetEntryVisible = true
    sc.companyId = company.companyId
    def newUs = userPort.addUser(company.getCompanyId(), false, password, password, false, ui.username, ui.email, 0, null, 'IT', ui.name, null, ui.surname, 0, 0, true, 1, 1, 1970, '', new long[0], new long[0], new long[0], new long[0], new AddressSoap[0], new EmailAddressSoap[0], new PhoneSoap[0], sites, new AnnouncementsDeliverySoap[0], false, sc)
    userPort.updateStatus(newUs.userId, 0, sc)
    userPort.updateAgreedToTermsOfUse(newUs.userId, true)
    newUs
}
```

This get executed without errors, the user is available but is not associated to any site. How do I do it? Also calling three different service to insert a single user doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: Try re-indexing under Control Panel > Server Administration. It may be the case that user entity is not getting indexed.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help